# Static NSTableView with preset rows

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

Is it possible to create a `NSTableView` in Interface Builder that has a preset number of rows so that the table can be used as a form?

I have a view that requires a form of various labels and textfields. I've tried using single labels and textfields but it looks poor. Same with the `NSForm` which additional put a couple of restrictions on layout and cell content.

So a table view looks very polished as a form view. What I would optimally like to do is drag seven `TextTableViewCell`s into a static `NSTableView` in IB and set labels in the first column and dynamically set values in the second column rows.

But if I build it my seven rows disappeared. How can I get an `NSTableView` to act static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Anc Ainu pointed out, as of OS X 10.10 it is possible to use static tableViews in OS X. You have to set the `usesStaticContents` property on `NSTableView` to make it behave like a static tableView on iOS. According to the docs:

> A static table does not rely on a data source to provide the number of rows. A static table view’s contents are set at design time and can be changed programmatically as needed. Typically, you do not change the contents of a static table view after setting them.
>
> In Xcode, any rows you add to a static table are saved in the corresponding nib or storyboard file and loaded with the rest of the table at runtime. You can add table rows programmatically to a static table view using the insertRowsAtIndexes:withAnimation: method. When adding rows programmatically, your table view delegate must implement the tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: method to provide the corresponding view for any new rows. You can also remove rows at any time using the removeRowsAtIndexes:withAnimation: method.

Please remember that this property is one available on OS X 10.10 and later.

Comment: What about `usesStaticContents` available in OSX 10.10
Link : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTableView/usesStaticContents

Comment: You are totally right! I was unaware of this property. Edited my answer right away! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to create these static views in the table view in IB ?

Comment: I have the same question, can I lay out a set of static views in an NSTableView in interface builder, like you can with iOS static tableviews?